# Can Windows 7 use hibernate and still wake up to record tv shows with Media Center

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center, hibernate

Currently I only use sleep on my Windows 7 pc. To save some power I would like to start using hibernate mode.

Does Windows 7 wake up from hibernate mode, to record tv shows I have programmed to record with Media Center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have confirmed Media Center in Windows 7 does wake-up to record shows from hibernate (S4) if your motherboard supports it. My motherboard doesn't support S3 (suspend-to-RAM) so got stuck using hibernate instead. The system wakes from hibernate up to record shows, execute scheduled tasks and performs backups just as my other hosts which use standby instead.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [thread](http://www.sevenforums.com/media-center/23984-wake-up-sleep-record.html) it works for some people and not for others.

Whether it works or not seems to be a function of the motherboard, but in general it should wake up.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that it can wake from Standby ([ACPI S3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface#Power_States)) but **not from Hibernate** (ACPI S4).

My reasoning is that under hibernation, the essential hardware (CPU and RAM, but also expansions such as network and TV tuners) are actually **powered off**, so there is no way to trigger a power-on.

Besides, the extra power saved between standby and hibernate would be negligible, likely no more than 2 Watts difference. You'd be doing just as well using standby, and your machine will resume faster as well. (2 Watt can amount to something over a year, but consider if it's worth it to you.)

Comment: This isn't strictly true and is largely motherboard dependent.  Some motherboards can wake from S4 using the real time clock.  In Linux this is shown in the syslog and is determined by your motherboard's FADT.  The RTC stays powered on in S4, and this turns the system back on.

Although, in general it's probably easier just to put the machine into S3, it will wake much faster and the power different is fairly small.  In the US, 1 Watt of power ~ $1/yr.

Comment: 1W = 1$/year is a simple value to remember. For those systems that can use the system clock, I'd guess that this can be used to power-on at a specific daily time, but not as-needed by Windows Media Center?

Comment: Why 2 downvotes? Is this not useful? Is this not correct? If so then please explain, so we can all learn from your wise minds... Psh!

Answer (score 1):

Try this program, "Wakeup on Standby"

http://www.dennisbabkin.com/php/download.php?what=WOSB

This can wake up Windows 7 from hibernation.  I know it works for sleep mode and hibernation in windows 7, as I have tested it.  The developer says its compatible up to windows Vista.  Its not yet compatible with Windows 7.  However, if you right click on the program, goto properties/compatibility, and then run it in "compatibility mode" for windows vista, it will function properly in Windows 7, otherwise you might not see the icon in the system tray.  You can then set all sorts of scripts for loading software on Wake or shutting down the computer, or whatever. This is a great program, + free! I recommend it.

Key words: Wake windows 7 from Sleep, wakeup windows 7, wake timer, wake hibernation, wake sleep, force wake up

Answer (score 0):

The way it works is as follows:

When we say we "power off" the computer, this isn't technically true.  The short answer is that the mainboard (motherboard for women, fatherboard of men) still receives power.  Even in S5 ("powered off") - if you open your PC case, most mainboards have a small LED to show you that they are still receiving power.  The power isn't coming from the clock's battery - it only powers the RTC - Real Time Clock.

This electricity is connected to several things - one of them is the computer's power switch.  If you notice, the power switch is connected NOT to your power supply, but to your mainboard, so obviously there has to be power there.

A computer can be "woken up" from Hibernate.  Even powered off.  The only way to really power off a computer is to turn off the switch on the back - that is the power supply's ON?OFF switch - that or pull the power cord.

So the mainboard always has power.  What it does with it is mainboard dependent.

Comment: Nice explanation, alas it has nothing to do with the question.